# Income Prediction using Joint Classifier and Regression Models

Tags: regression, classification, boosting

so I have an Income Regression task for which I'm building an XGBoost Model. When I built my first model there was an issue that the low incomes would get highly overestimated and high incomes underestimated. I was recommended to split the incomes by segments and create a Regression model for each one, then use a classifier to classify the income segment (My predicted income is the dot product of all 3 predictions and classification probabilities). This approach actually proved to be better in almost all metrics and due to the nature of the data outperformed just a single XGBoost approach.

So my flow is this: 3 XGBoost Regression Models for incomes (<600, 600-1500, >1500) and an XGBClassifier. One issue I'm currently facing, is that while the individual Regression models perform very good, e.g. the <600 model has low loss on the <600 data, the whole model performs significantly worse on the <600 data. This difference is caused by the classification error.

I've tried tuning all the models individually, but I was thinking if there's a way to have train individual models on the shared loss somehow (Similar to how you would in Deep Learning), or maybe my approach is flawed from the beginning and It's better to stick to a single Regression model?

I haven't been able to find any sources on similarly structured model, so any help & guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you plan to use your model when you don’t know the income?

Comment: It is completely normal that low incomes will be over- and high ones underestimated. This is regression to the mean, [this may be helpful](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5567/1352). This does not mean that there is nothing you can do; it merely means that stratifying by outcome is usually not very enlightening.

Comment: @Dave sorry, can you elaborate? I do have the income variable in my training data, the classifier classifies the segment (which it learned from using income) and then I predict every regression's outcome and return the dot product with classification probabilities as a prediction.

Comment: At some point, you won’t have the income. After all, if you always knew the income, you wouldn’t need to predict it. I do not see a way to use your approach when you don’t know the income, as your approach seems to use the income as a feature.

Comment: @Dave I'm not using income as a feature, I'm using predicted income segment which classifies clients based on their other data (monthly payment, how many loans, e.t.c)

Comment: The classifier predictions are then evaluated on true income split into segments.